# Is it possible to have more than one guard node?

Tags: circuit

Is it possible to have more than one guard node?

[The Tor Project Website](https://support.torproject.org/tbb/tbb-2/) says that the guard node is always the same and when viewing the circuit for the current site, there's a note that says "Your Guard node may not change."

But every now and then there's a node that pops up out of nowhere having a different IP address and being from a different location that appears to be a guard node that is there by itself and never generates any circuits.

Is this a feature of tor or is this something that looks suspicious?

[image: Onion Circuits Screenshot 1]

[image: Onion Circuits Screenshot 2]

EDIT: I want to point out that the mysterious node as seen in the screenshot is only one example. I have seen at least another one like it pop up and just sit there without generating a circuit.
They usually stay there until I reset the connection to the internet, i.e., disconnect and connect again.

Answer (score 1):

(the only way i know it) yes it is possible to have mutlipe tor guard nodes first you should setup whonix gateway which route all your `VM` traffics to the tor network
https://www.whonix.org/wiki/KVM

then you should setup multiple whonix gateways https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Multiple_Whonix-Gateway#KVM

attach both of them to the machine and then you should setup redundancy

no idea why you need such a setup whonix alone is pretty secure

about nodes i am not sure what's going on here it might be new nodes joined in tor networks or maybe it's gov but tor networks designed in way that it always uses circuit and the data it self is encrypted tor declared that nodes have little information about packets just to route them to another node

how do you know it's not being circuits ?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. Can you explain more about what you mean by "gov"?

Comment: no problem. goverments

Comment: If the Answer was helpful, please click "Accept Answer" and upvote it.